# The template of app-root component is not repeating upon multiple references of app-root tag in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have generated the base Angular application using `angular-cli` and the application is loading fine. Then I have repeated `app-root` in `index.html` but surprisingly the `app-root` component template is not visible twice,  the template is displayed only once. Even if I refer `app-root` component multiple times, the template is appearing only once. Below is my code.

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

However I can see the  multiple `app-root` tags in the Elements section while inspecting through chrome developer tools. Why the template of `app-root` is not getting repeated as many times as I refer `app-root` tag in `index.html` file?

[image: Inspect Elements]

Answer (score 0):

That `app-root` component is your root bootstrap component so mentioning it multiple times is not gonna do anything, angular will look for first reference of app-root in html and will treat it as starting point of your application.